# glsl has an error: cannot convert from 'highp float' to 'highp 3-component vector of float'

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

GLSL gives an error like this:

> cannot convert from 'highp float' to 'highp 3-component vector of float'

T have picked the error part:

```c
vec3 bRgb = texture2D(u_img1, vUv).rgb;
vec3 aRgb = texture2D(u_aImg, vUv).rgb;
vec3 target1 = aRgb * bRgb;
vec3 alum = dot( aRgb, w );
vec3 blum = dot( bRgb, w );
vec3 clum = dot( target1, w );

vec3 target2 = (alum + blum) / (2. * clum); // This is the error line
gl_FragColor = vec4(target2, 1.);
```

I could find the error line ,but i dont know how to make it run.

Comment: https://codepen.io/aprildove/pen/oyeBJb?editors=1011 this is a demo link

Comment: The dot product returns a float and the shader cannot implicitly convert float to vec3. Try wrapping your dot products in a vec3 like vec3(dot( aRgb, w ));

Comment: https://codepen.io/aprildove/pen/oyeBJb  @TJGreen  i correct my code , but it may have some problem     

for this part, 'target1' maybe okay, but target2 is not like target1's behavior, can you help make the target2 just like target1 's good behavior ?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, your issue is in the line vec3 target2 = (alum + blum) / (2. * clum);. The division causes all the colors to be 1.0 or greater rendering the image as white. you can increase the value clum is multiplied by to get an image to show up...